# cockies is null when HttpWebResponse in formauthentication

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf, signals

I have an application where I used signalr. and formAuthentication. I am trying to connect hub class from WCF service. IN WCF service code is as bellow:

```
 Public Class Demo
    {
    public Demo()
            {
        var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:47315/")
                        {
                            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
                        };
        connection.CookieContainer.Add(GetAuthCookie("user1", "pass"));
 chatHubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("servicesSatatuseHub");
                 connection.Start().Wait();
     }

    private static System.Net.Cookie GetAuthCookie(string user, string pass)
            {
                //var http = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:47315/module/account/login.aspx") as HttpWebRequest;
                var http = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:47315//module/account/login.aspx") as HttpWebRequest;
                http.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                http.Method = "POST";
                http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                http.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                //var postData = "UserName=" + user + "&Password=" + pass + "";
                var postData = "UserName=" + user + "&Password=" + pass + "";
                byte[] dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                http.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
                using (var postStream = http.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
                }
                System.Net.Cookie authCookie;
                using (var response = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    authCookie = response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];//authCookie = null
                }

                httpResponse.Close();
                return cookie;
            }
}
```

Every thing is fine but Cookie is null on this code

```
authCookie = <p>response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];//authCookie = null
```

Due to cookie null hubconnection is fail.

Thanks in  advance

Comment: Why do you have this: `http.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();`?

Comment: to set the authentication cookie on the hubconnection.

Comment: Did you look at what's in response.Cookies? Is the cookie being passed to you in the response headers?

Comment: What should I check in response.Cookies?

Comment: @RahmanyUsama Uh, that the value you're looking for is there?

Comment: No. Cookie is null in header. in header property SetCookie =null.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. If the server isn't giving you a cookie, you won't get a cookie. You'll have to check your server code. Debug you login, see if it's working.

Comment: How to check server provide cookies to WCF service?

Comment: I check in header property header property SetCookie="ASP.NET_SessionId=4wl0usjmdn0xmggzehs1z5rm; path=/; HttpOnly"

Comment: But you are not using the `CookieContainer` in `GetAuthCookie` so what's the reason for newing it up? In the `Demo` constructor you are using it like this:`connection.CookieContainer` but if they are the same object and you are newing it up then that could be the problem. Just my guess...

Comment: Please, can you suggest me where and how should I use the connection.CookieContainer.